# How can I render Mathjax expression in react js, I am using from mathjax.org?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mathjax

**Index.html**

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({
          extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
          jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
          showProcessingMessages: false,
          showMathMenu: false,
          showMathMenuMSIE: false,
          messageStyle: "none",
          tex2jax: {
              inlineMath: [
                  ["$", "$"],
                  ["\\(", "\\)"]
              ]
          },
          "HTML-CSS": {
              linebreaks: {
                  automatic: true,
          width: "container"
              },
              preferredFont: "qikikFont"
          }
      });
    </script>
```

So here I am trying to load mathjax
and in component level I am trying to render a math equation
Can anyone please guide me in a correct procedure,I am using Mathjax from winodw ?

```js
export default class Performance extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        window.MathJax.Hub.Config({ //config is undefined 
          skipStartupTypeset: true,
          extensions: ["tex2jax.js", "TeX/AMSmath.js"],
          jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
          tex2jax: {
              inlineMath: [["$", "$"]],
              processEscapes: true
          }
      });
      }
      renderMath() {
        var HUB = window.MathJax.Hub;
        HUB.Queue(["Typeset", HUB, "render-me"]);
      }

      render() {
        return (              
            <p onCllick={this.renderMath}>Performance works</p>                    
        );
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script
  id="MathJax-script"
  async
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3.0.1/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"
></script>
```

So I am not supposed to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjax-react and any other npm packages.
please refer this code in sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-monad-98ewn?file=/src/MAthjax.js:1125-1135

Comment: You can try a package to make life easier for you... I wrote one, feel free to try it out :) [better-react-mathjax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-react-mathjax)